# using aws Mysql in Vue.JS using SQL

Tags: mysql, amazon-web-services, vue.js, amazon-aurora

I wanna ask, how to connect and **query SQL** using **AWS Mysql/auroraDB** and **VueJs**? i find a lot in google search but all using GraphQL and using PHP. i want to avoid using PHP and fully JS

Answer (score 0):

You can use node.js and its frameworks for creating APIs.

Comment: do you have any tutorial that i can refer to? sorry i just start using vue last week. i dont understand how vue works

Comment: @RahmanGhaffar You can refer to this https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pKd0Rpw7O48